# strend, function that checks the occurence of a pattern at the end of a string

Tags: c, beginner, strings, pointers

> Write a function `strend(s, t)` which returns `1` if the string `t` occurs at the end of `s`, and `0` otherwise.

Here is my solution:

```
unsigned int strend(char *source, char *pattern) {
    char *saver = pattern;

    while(*source)
        source++;

    while(*saver)
        saver++;

    while(saver >= pattern) 
        if(*saver-- != *source--)     
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

There are 2 `while` loops that will run until `source` and `saver` will point to the end of the string that they are representing. You will notice the presence of the variable `saver`, at the end of the second while loop this variable will have the value `pattern + X`, where `X` represent the number of charachters in the string `pattern`.

By using the variable `saver` I know when to stop the third loop. When `saver` is less than `pattern` that means that every charachter in the string `pattern` was compared with the coresponding one in `source`. At each iteration of the loop I check if the current charachter that `saver` points to is equal to the coresponding charachter in `source`.

Here is my second version:

```
unsigned int strend(char *source, char *pattern) {
    char *saver = pattern + strlen(pattern);
    source += strlen(source);

    while(saver >= pattern)
        if(*source-- != *saver--)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

There is a dependency between my second implementation of `strend` and `strlen`. I, also, have some problems with the naming of the variable `saver`. What would be a more suggestive name for its purpose?

The exercise can be found at page 121 in K&R second edition.

Comment: The "dependency" on `strlen` in your second example is generally a good thing. Its reuse of existing functionality lets you focus on new problems, rather than ones that are already solved. (But it's good to know how to roll your own, too!)

Comment: I propose changing `char*` to `const char*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you have the naming problem because the code use the variable for multiple purposes. First, it points to the end of the `pattern`, then it's used for the pointer of the current character under test. (See below.)

In the first snippet there two identical while loops:

```
while(*source)
    source++;

while(*saver)
    saver++;
```

It's a nice catch that you changed them to `strlen()`. If you don't want `#include <string.h>` you still could extract it to a function to remove some code duplication:

```
char *getLastChar(char *input) {
    while(*input)
        input++;
    return input;
}
```

Here is a refactored version of the first snippet:

```
#define DIFFERENT 0
#define EQUAL 1

unsigned int strend1(char *source, char *pattern) {
    char *patternEnd = getLastChar(pattern);
    char *sourceEnd = getLastChar(source);

    char *currentPatternChar = patternEnd;
    char *currentSourceChar = sourceEnd;
    while (currentSourceChar >= source && currentPatternChar >= pattern) {
        if (*currentSourceChar != *currentPatternChar) {
            return DIFFERENT;
        }

        currentPatternChar--;
        currentSourceChar--;
    }
    return EQUAL;
}
```

Some things to note:

1. I've added another check to the `while` loop: `currentSourceChar >= source`. It handles those cases (fixes a bug) when the pattern is longer that the `source` string.
2. I've used two constants for the return values instead of magic numbers. It helps readers and maintainers because it shows the intent of `0` and `1`.
3. The `patternEnd` and `currentPatternChar` variables are basically the same (as well as their source pair) but I think it improves readability a little bit. First, you have a pointer to the last char (`patternEnd`), then another variables is used for iteration (`currentPatternChar`). (A good compiler will optimize it for you.)

Answer (score 10):

I see no point in avoiding the use of Standard Library functions.  Learning to
use them is part of becoming a proficient C programmer.  Hence using `strlen`
is good and reinventing `strcmp` or `memcmp`, as you have done, is bad.  Making the return
value unsigned is just extra typing/noise and achieves nothing.  Here is a
simplified version:

```
int strend1(const char *str, const char *pattern)
{
    size_t plen = strlen(pattern);
    size_t slen = strlen(str);
    return (plen <= slen) 
           && !memcmp(pattern, str + slen - plen, plen) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Note that the parameters are `const`.

Comment: I'm practicing my terminology. Can strend be considered a wrapper for memcmp?

Comment: A wrapper would modify the interface in some way, maybe providing a default parameter (eg the length for `memcmp`) or making the function work with different types.  As such I'd expect the wrapper to be able 'naturally' (ie without it being contrived) to take a name derived from the wrapped function.  I don't think that is really true of `strend` and `memcmp` - you might rename it `memcmp_end` but that does not really reflect what it does because no 'end' is defined, except in terms of string parameters, which `memcmp` does not take.  So no, I don't consider it a wrapper.